# jsnetworkx: graph to file

Tags: javascript, json, networkx, jsnetworkx

I am using JSnetworkx to work with a complicated graph (directed, with labels and node types). Basically, it is a constructor/editor for specific graphs.

**Question:** What is the proper way to save the graph to a file, so that I could visualize and edit it every time I run my JS code?

I found [this](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/readwrite/json_graph.html) for Networkx, but jsnx doesn't seem to support these functions...